# SymmetricAlgorithm' does not contain a definition for 'Create'

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-4.6.1

I'm trying to work on ASP.NET 5 application. Here is a class and it looks good (no red curly underlines). But when I try to build, it gives error - `SymmetricAlgorithm' does not contain a definition for 'Create'`

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace SalesBook
{
    public static class Encryptor
    {
        private static byte[] EncryptString(string data)
        {
            byte[] byteData = Common.GetByte(data);
            SymmetricAlgorithm algo = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create();

        }
    }
}
```

I'm using .net 4.6.1. 
Any help?

Comment: Could be a dependency issue. (Usually is). What frameworks are you using? Can you post your project.json?

Answer (score 5):

This method has not been ported to .NET Core. The recommended alternative is to use the specific `Create` method associated with the algorithm you need:

```
var algorithm = Aes.Create();
```

On CoreCLR, it will automatically determine and return the best implementation, depending on your OS environement.

If you don't need .NET Core support, you can remove the `dnxcore50`/`dotnet5.4` from your project.json.

Comment: Thank you, but what does Aes mean here?

Comment: AES is the most common symmetric algorithm and is supported on CoreCLR.

Answer (score 0):

This method **SymmetricAlgorithm.Create()** is now Obsolete as per the Microsoft  documentation of [SymmetricAlgorithm.Create Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.create?view=net-7.0)

There is exceptions using these method and some potential issues too.
[image]

The SymmetricAlgorithm.Create() method in .NET does not specify a particular symmetric encryption algorithm, and the default algorithm used can vary depending on the .NET Framework version and the platform. The actual algorithm used is determined by the underlying cryptographic service provider (CSP) or cryptographic library configured on the system.

AES is widely considered the standard symmetric encryption algorithm due to its security and efficiency. To ensure the use of a specific symmetric algorithm like AES, you should create an instance of that algorithm explicitly using Aes.Create() instead

```
using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
{
    // Your encryption/decryption code
    // ...
}
```